Text wrapping in longtable not working
I have the following problem. I'm creating a table using the longtable package since it will have more rows than the ones I'm upoading here in the example. However, some text as in the second row ignore text wrapping and stays over the rest of the cells next to it. So that's why I would like to know how could I try to find a way to solve it.
I tried using the following tutorial but it didn't work for me
https://youtu.be/qruVIGf5nqE?si=U3SLtqPCAZnLR7Av

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in}

\begin{document}
\section{Longtable problem}


\begin{longtable}[>\centering p{2cm}]{@{}llll>\centering m{1cm}ll@{}}
\caption{Longtable Wrapping}
\label{tab:Longtable_textWrap}\\
\toprule
No     & RQ1       & RQ2    & RQ3    & RQ4       & RQ5    & RQ6    \\* \midrule
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
\bottomrule
\endfoot
%
\endlastfoot
%
{[}1{]}  &          & 8      &        & 68,69,84,85,86,87,88,89  &        & 4,8    \\
{[}2{]}  & 7        & 4      &        &           &        &        \\
{[}3{]}  &          &        & 3      &           &        & 1,8    \\
{[}4{]}  &          & 3      &        & 57,58,63  &        &        \\
{[}5{]}  &          &        & 68,71  &           &        &        \\
{[}6{]}  &          &        &        & 4,5       &        &        \\
{[}7{]}  & 2,4,5,7  &        & 88     & 68,87     &        &        \\
{[}8{]}  &          & 1,1    &        &           &        &        \\
{[}9{]}  & 5        &        &        & 10,11,20  &        &        \\
{[}10{]} &          &        & 41-44  &           &        &        \\
{[}11{]} & 7,8,13   &        & 23-34  & 37        &        & 110-116 \\
{[}12{]} &          & 1,2,10 &        &           &        &        \\ 
{[}13{]} & 3        & 2-7    &        & 3         &        &        \\* 
\end{longtable}





\end{document}


welcome! your syntax seems a bit confused ;). what is the >\centering p{2cm} supposed to do? you've given it as an option to the environment, but you can only use c, r or l there. (I think longtable should give an error, but it doesn't.) is it supposed to be a spec for the first column? that would make 8 columns. the basic problem right now is that the long entry can't break lines because there are no spaces and no hyphenation points. it doesn't even give a warning about that p.

Ass supplement to nice  @cfr answer (+1). With use of longtblr of tabularray package table code is shorter and to my opinion more clear:
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.1pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}   % load booktabs package

\begin{document}

\section{Longtable problem}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Longtable Wrapping},
  label = {tab:Longtable_textWrap}
                ]{width=0.9\linewidth,  % in the case, that table width 
                                        % can be equal text width, omit 
                                        % this option
                  colspec = { @{} r *{3}{X[c]} X[1.2,c] *{2}{X[c]} @{} },
                  cell{2-Z}{1} = {preto=[, appto=]},    % add brackets around 
                                                        % numbers in the first column
                  rowhead = 1}          % repeat column headers on next pages
%% headers and footers
    \toprule
No  & RQ1       & RQ2       & RQ3    & RQ4       & RQ5    & RQ6    \\ 
    \midrule
%% body of table
  1  &          & 8         &        & 68, 69, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89  
                                                 &        & 4, 8   \\
  2  & 7        & 4         &        &           &        &        \\
  3  &          &           & 3      &           &        & 1,8    \\
  4  &          & 3         &        & 57, 58, 63&        &        \\
  5  &          &           & 68, 71 &           &        &        \\
  6  &          &           &        & 4, 5      &        &        \\
  7  & 2, 4, 5, 7 
                &           & 88     & 68, 87    &        &        \\
  8  &          & 1,1       &        &           &        &        \\
  9  & 5        &           &        & 10, 11, 20&        &        \\
  10 &          &           & 41--44 &           &        &        \\
  11 & 7, 8, 13 &           & 23--34 & 37        &        & 110--116 \\
  12 &          & 1, 2, 10  &        &           &        &        \\
  13 & 3        & 2--7      &        & 3         &        &        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


Default is longtblr as well longtblr horizontal centered. longtblr automatic add to captions on the next pages labels (Continue) and to footers except on the last page Continued on next page. The style of the last you can change/define with \SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{<desired style>}. For exampler \footnotesize\itshape.
Since table is not sufficient long both of aforementioned options is not show.
Edit:
Let me mention, that all (excellent) features of the tabularray package we pay with (usual a bit) longer compilation time which at complex tables can become quite long ...

@cfr, you are right. \tabularray` has beside many pros also a bib cons: speedy penalty. I will edit answer asap ...

And that speed penalty can be quite important on OverLeaf.

@daleif I guess the OP doesn't use overleaf ... or has only just started the thesis ....

The optional argument to longtable can take c, r or l (according to the documentation), so >\centering p{1cm} is out. longtable doesn't tell you this by reporting an error, though. Indeed, it doesn't even issue a warning. It is probably a good thing this fails because this argument affects the alignment of the entire table and you probably do not want a table only 2cm wide. I replaced this with c, which is the default anyway.
m{} or p{} allow line breaks, but only if TeX can find places to break lines. That means something like a space or a hyphenation point. A string of comma-separated numbers has no places where TeX can break the line, so it can't do anything but issue a warning.
If I insert some spaces, it works fine, but looks a bit odd (to my way of thinking), so I changed it to p and added \raggedright so the alignment is consistent with other columns. I also played around with the first column. I doubt you need the square brackets at all, so I'd just remove them. In case you do need them for some reason, I tried to come up with something a bit more consistent looking.
I'd strongly recommend looking at the siunitx package, even though you aren't using units here, for ways to display numbers in tables. You should also consider using sans-serif for at least some of this, as it generally makes for cleaner-looking tables.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in}

\begin{document}

\section{Longtable problem}

\begin{longtable}[c]{ @{} >{[}r<{]} lll >{\raggedright}p{2.25cm} ll @{} }

  %% headers and footers
  \caption{Longtable Wrapping}
  \label{tab:Longtable_textWrap}\\
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}r}{No} & RQ1 & RQ2 & RQ3 & RQ4 & RQ5 & RQ6  \\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead

  \multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, cont'd}\\
  \addlinespace
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}r}{No} & RQ1 & RQ2 & RQ3 & RQ4 & RQ5 & RQ6  \\ 
  \midrule
  \endhead

  \bottomrule
  \multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (cont'd on next page)} \\
  \endfoot
 
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot

  %% body of table
  1  &          & 8      &        & 68, 69, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89  & & 4, 8 \\
  2  & 7        & 4      &        &           &        &        \\
  3  &          &        & 3      &           &        & 1,8    \\
  4  &          & 3      &        & 57, 58, 63&        &        \\
  5  &          &        & 68, 71 &           &        &        \\
  6  &          &        &        & 4, 5      &        &        \\
  7  & 2, 4, 5, 7 &      & 88     & 68, 87    &        &        \\
  8  &          & 1,1    &        &           &        &        \\
  9  & 5        &        &        & 10, 11, 20&        &        \\
  10 &          &        & 41--44 &           &        &        \\
  11 & 7, 8, 13 &        & 23--34 & 37        &        & 110--116 \\
  12 &          & 1, 2, 10 &      &           &        &        \\
  13 & 3        & 2--7   &        & 3         &        &        \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}


I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot.

@Mico thank you very much. now I feel lazy. two people have edited my answer in not many more minutes.
